# Serially assign values to OrderedDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, ordereddictionary

I have two key-value pairs, and now I want to fill up the larger one with values from the smaller one in a serial manner.

```
  OrderedDictionary pickersPool = new OrderedDictionary(); // Small
  OrderedDictionary pickersToTicketMap = new OrderedDictionary(); // Big

  pickersPool.Add("emp1", 44);
  pickersPool.Add("emp2", 543);
```

Now I need to update pickersToTicketMap to look like this:

```
   ("100", 44);
   ("109", 543);
   ("13", 44);
   ("23", 543);
```

So basically I need the pickersPool value to cycle through the keys of the pickersToTicketMap dictionary.

I need pickerPool values to keep cycling pickersToTicketMap and updating its value serially.

The pickersToTicketMap orderedlist initially has a value of:

```
   ("100", "null");
   ("109", "null");
   ("13", "null");
   ("23", "null");
```

so I need for the values of PickerPool orderedDictionary to fill up those nulls in a repeated fashion.

Comment: Where do the 100, 109, 13 and 23 parts come from? I'm afraid I'm finding your question very hard to understand... Please edit it to be a *lot* clearer.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do something like a sql join in c#?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot this is not sql but c#

Comment: So it sounds like you need a *list* of pickers, and then have a nested loop to populate the `pickersToTicketMap`...

Comment: yes @JonSkeet , thats exactly what i want, in this fashion. 44, 543, next picker, ..... last picker, 44, 543 ......

Comment: So why are you populating a *dictionary* with your tickets rather than a *list*?

Comment: What if there are more `pickersPool` than `pickersToTicketMap`? What if the latter is not divisible by the former?

Comment: So you want to update the large dictionary's values with consecutive and repeating values from the possibly smaller one? If that's what you want i could post an answer, but it's closed now.

Comment: Try the following code

            `object[] keys = new object[pickersToTicketMap.Keys.Count];
            pickersToTicketMap.Keys.CopyTo(keys,0);
            object[] values=new object[pickersPool.Values.Count];
            pickersPool.Values.CopyTo(values,0);
            byte i = 0;
            pickersToTicketMap.Clear();
            foreach(var key in keys)
            {
                pickersToTicketMap.Add(key, values[i++]);
            }`

Comment: You can repeat the smaller collection with `Enumerable.Repeat`. You have to claculate the count with `largeDict.Count/smallDict.Count+largeDict.Count%smallDict.COunt`. Then you can use `SelectMany` to flatten it and `ToList` to create a collection. Then you can use a `for`-loop to update the larger dictionary which you can access via index.

Comment: @CodeCaster: i think it's quite clear, isn't it? Maybe you also want to vote to reopen.

Comment: @Tim _"Unclear what you're asking"_ can also be used for "give me the code" questions. This is not particularly the first instance of this question, it's lacking research and what OP has tried, and only after the last edit it became somewhat more clear what OP wants. Edit: alright, with four reopen votes there's bound to come someone along to reopen it, why not me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should start with a `List<string>` (or possibly a `List<int>`, given that they all seem to be integers...) rather than populating your map with empty entries to start with. So something like:

```
List<string> tickets = new List<string> { "100", "109", "13", "23" };
```

Then you can populate your `pickersToTicketMap` as:

```
var pickers = pickersPool.Values;
var pickerIterator = pickers.GetEnumerator();
foreach (var ticket in tickets)
{
    if (!pickerIterator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Start the next picker...
        pickerIterator = pickers.GetEnumerator();
        if (!pickerIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No pickers available!");
        }
    }
    ticketToPickerMap[ticket] = pickerIterator.Current;
}
```

Note that I've changed the name from `pickersToTicketMap` to `ticketToPickerMap` because that appears to be what you really mean - the key is the ticket, and the value is the picker.

Also note that I'm *not* disposing of the iterator from `pickers`. That's generally a bad idea, but in this case I'm assuming that the iterator returned by `OrderedDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator()` doesn't need disposal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes - I voted to close because it was originally very unclear. It was then clarified to the extent that I could answer, then some other folks thought it was still too unclear to answer. Have voted to reopen now.

Comment: this line 
ticketToPickerMap[ticket] = pickerIterator.Current

is not returning a value of "System.Collections.DictionaryEntry" instead of picker number

Comment: @Edwin: Are you sure you've got *exactly* my code, with `var pickers = pickersPool.Values;`? I'm deliberately iterating over just the values collection, *not* over `pickersPool`.

Answer (score 1):

There may be what you are looking for:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int i = 0;
// Cast OrderedDictionary to IEnumarable<DictionaryEntry> to be able to use System.Linq
object[] keys = pickersToTicketMap.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Select(x=>x.Key).ToArray();
IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry> pickersPoolEnumerable =  pickersPool.Cast<DictionaryEntry>();
// iterate over all keys (sorted)
foreach (object key in keys)
{
    // Set the value of key to element i % pickerPool.Count
    // i % pickerPool.Count will return for Count = 2
    // 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...
    pickersToTicketMap[key] = pickersPoolEnumarable
        .ElementAt(i % pickersPool.Count).Value;
    i++;
}
```

PS: The `ToArray()` is required to have a separate copy of the keys, so you don't get a `InvalidOperationException` due to changing the element you are iterating over.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your code does exactly?

Comment: @CodeCaster added explanation

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the large dictionary's values with consecutive and repeating values from the possibly smaller one? I have two approaches in mind, one simpler:

1. You can repeat the smaller collection with `Enumerable.Repeat`. You have to calculate the count. Then you can use `SelectMany` to flatten it and `ToList` to create a collection. Then you can use a `for` loop to update the larger dictionary with the values in the list via an index:

   ```
   IEnumerable<int> values =  pickersPool.Values.Cast<int>();
   if (pickersPool.Count < pickersToTicketMap.Count)
   {
       // Repeat this collection until it has the same size as the larger collection
       values = Enumerable.Repeat( values,
           pickersToTicketMap.Count / pickersPool.Count
             + pickersToTicketMap.Count % pickersPool.Count
       )
       .SelectMany(intColl => intColl);
   }
   List<int> valueList = values.ToList();
   for (int i = 0; i < valueList.Count; i++)
       pickersToTicketMap[i] = valueList[i];
   ```
2. I would prefer the above approach, because it's more readable than my second which uses an "infinite" sequence. This is the extension method:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatEndless<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
   {
       while (true)
           foreach (var item in sequence)
               yield return item;
   }
   ```

Now you can use this code to update the larger dictionary's values:

```
var endlessPickersPool = pickersPool.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().RepeatEndless();
IEnumerator<DictionaryEntry> endlessEnumerator;
IEnumerator<string> ptmKeyEnumerator;
using ((endlessEnumerator = endlessPickersPool.GetEnumerator()) as IDisposable)
using ((ptmKeyEnumerator = pickersToTicketMap.Keys.Cast<string>().ToList().GetEnumerator()) as IDisposable)
{
    while (endlessEnumerator.MoveNext() && ptmKeyEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        DictionaryEntry pickersPoolItem = (DictionaryEntry)endlessEnumerator.Current;
        pickersToTicketMap[ptmKeyEnumerator.Current] = pickersPoolItem.Value;
    }
}
```

Note that it's important that I use `largerDict.Keys.Cast<string>().ToList()`, because I can't use the original `Keys` collection. You get an exception if you change it during enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jon skeet, although he modified my objects too much while trying to provide a hack for this.

After looking at your solution, I implemented the following, which works well for all my objects.

```
var pickerIterator = pickerPool.GetEnumerator();

foreach (DictionaryEntry ticket in tickets)
{
    if (!pickerIterator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Start the next picker...
        pickerIterator = pickerPool.GetEnumerator();
        if (!pickerIterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No pickers available!");
        }
    }
    ticketToPickerMap[ticket.Key] = pickerIterator.Value.ToString();
}
```